# HP Proliant Microserver Gen 8 Unable to see array as disk drive

Tags: hard-drive, raid, windows-server-2012-r2, hp

I'm a bit new to server ownership, but in no means new to IT.

I recently got an old microserver from my job, with a copy of Windows Server 2012 R2 and wanted to set it up for NAS or something similar for file sharing/storage/backup.

I currently have 2 250gb drives and 2 3tb drives installed, both set up as separate raid1 arrays.
The 250gb array was set up as my bootable drive, and currently shows up as the C: drive. The 3tb array does not show up as a drive at all, but it's showing up in device manager, so I know it's being seen by BIOS and the OS.

How do I get this to show up as a D: or E: drive in my file explorer?

Comment: Did you create any partition on the second array?

Comment: I have not! I've not done that before, so it seems I'll need to do some research.

Comment: Please read [How do I ask a good question](https://superuser.com/help/how-to-ask) then before asking a question on stackexchange

Comment: Gee, thanks so much. Fair enough. Won't be asking further questions on here then.

Comment: You can of course ask further questions here and I'm sure many would love to answer them. Still researching should be the first step to resolve a problem. 
If you could solve your problem by creating a partition, you might want to add an answer to your own question, it might help people in the future with the same problem!